# How do I select all elements w/ SASS except elements of specific parent?

Tags: css, sass

I want to do a standard reset on all HTML elements on my page(make the margin and padding 0) *except* those that are children of .raw-HTML.

Below is what I have that does not work (or even compile using SASS)

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,
p,blockquote,pre,
dl,dd,ol,ul,
form,fieldset,legend,
table,th,td,caption,
hr {

    &:not(.raw-HTML > &) {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after using a sub-optimal solution..

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
dl,
dd,
ol,
ul,
form,
fieldset,
legend,
table,
th,
td,
caption {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;


    .raw-HTML & {
        margin: inherit;
        padding: inherit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`not` doesn't accept multiple selectors, so that won't work. I don't know if there's a good way to do this, but you could try something like this:

```
*:not(.raw-HTML){
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,
    p,blockquote,pre,
    dl,dd,ol,ul,
    form,fieldset,legend,
    table,th,td,caption,
    hr {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that will result in *:not(.raw-HTML) p, selecting the .raw-HTML and not it's elements.

Comment: Yeah, when I was finally able to test it in jsfiddle and this didn't work. I'll leave the answer here for future reference if anyone needs to know what *doesn't* work!